# How can I display the user of a Forum?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to find out how I can display the username of a user. For example user admin posts a forum, then I would see **Created By: admin** on the forum page, instead I can only fish out the ID.

I don't know a much about mongoose and I need someone who is familiar with it.

**My Forum Model:**

You see I have only ref: 'user' and this is grabbing the ObjectId("") from the User.

```
const forumSchema = ({
   forumName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   forumDescription: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   user: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user'
   },
   published_on: {
      type: String,
      default: moment().format("LLL")
   },
});
```

**my userModel:**

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   userID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   isAdministrator: {
      type: Boolean,
      deafult: false,
  },

});
```

**Front-end :**

As you can see only in `{forum.user}` there I can see the id from the user but I want his name not the id

```
 <footer className="blockquote-footer">
    Created by:{forum.user}
    Created on:{forum.published_on.substring(0,300)}
 </footer>
```

What I got in MongoDB Compass :

```
_id:ObjectId(61e052686147a6f0bd1e65df)
forumName:test33
forumDescription:"test."
published_on:"January 13, 2022 5:25 PM"
user:ObjectId(61dd83db2b8b9b6e2a8e7f0b)
__v:0
```

What I got in Postman:

```
{
  "_id": "61e054809b71d933dbefae22",
  "forumName": "testtest",
  "forumDescription": "testing.",
  "published_on": "January 13, 2022 5:27 PM",
  "user": {
    "_id": "61dd83db2b8b9b6e2a8e7f0b",
    "userID": "admin",
    "userName": "admin",
    "password": "$2b$10$qwAZspGbchBkZ6eoe8ODxOiLeOrK2J3cltrLMKlVB/6TRhL5e1qAy",
    "isAdministrator": true,
    "__v": 0
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Forum Action list :

```
export const createNoteAction =
  (forumName, forumDescription) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTES_CREATE_REQUEST,
      });

      const {
        userLogin: { userInfo },
      } = getState();

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token.token}`,
        },
      };
      const url = "http://localhost:8080/forum/";

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        url,
        { forumName, forumDescription },
        config
      );

      dispatch({
        type: NOTES_CREATE_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({
        type: NOTES_CREATE_FAIL,
        payload: message,
      });
    }
  };
```

My Frontend page:

```
{forum &&
        forum.map((forum) => (
          <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
            <Accordion.Item style={{ margin: 10 }} key={forum._id}>
              <Accordion.Header style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              <span
                  style={{
                    color: "black",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    flex: 1,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    fontSize: 18,
                  }}
                >
                      {forum.forumName}
                </span>
                </Accordion.Header>
                <Accordion.Body>
                <blockquote className="blockquote mb-0">
                  <ReactMarkdown>{forum.forumDescription}</ReactMarkdown>
                  <footer className="blockquote-footer">     
                  Created by:{forum.user.userName}                      
                        Created on: {forum.published_on.substring(0,300)}               
                      </footer>
```

Comment: did you `console.log` the `forum` object inside the `map` function and verify if you've received the data properly?

Comment: I do it now to check ..

Comment: No. I got only the userid @PrajwalKulkarni

Comment: Are you getting the user id when you log the user name? Also, make sure that you're using the same endpoint in your application, as the one used in postman.

Comment: I can only write my console.log() over render() function and if I type their console.log(forum.userName) it´s undefined @PrajwalKulkarni

Comment: Shouldn't that be `forum.user.userName`?

Comment: I tried this .. this is also not working. @PrajwalKulkarni I wrote you on Twitter

Answer (score 0):

You have to [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) users inside forums :

`Forum.find().populate("user")`

Now you will have full user objects, not only their `_id`.

Comment: This is not working .. :/

Comment: what are you sending to the frontend

Comment: I got on Postman everything .. I want to have it on the Frontend that´s the problem

Comment: then try `forum.user.userName`

Comment: I tried it already.. it does not work .. I edited my createAction so you can see